# How to solve two symbolic equations with Normal CDF (pnorm) using R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, cdf

I want to solve these two equations numerically using R

Equation 1: pnorm((c2+1)/5)-pnorm((c1+1)/5) = 0.025

Equation 2: pnorm((c2-1)/5)-pnorm((c1-1)/5) = 0.025

I need to find the values for c1 and c2

I tried to use rSymPy and Ryacas but couldn't actually figure out how to do it.

R code I tried

solve([Eq(pnorm((c2+1)/5)-pnorm((c1+1)/5), 0.025), Eq(pnorm((c2-1)/5)-pnorm((c1-1)/5), 0.02)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the package 'nleqslv' in R? Using it, you can easily get a solution. Solve won't work because you have a non-linear system of equations that can't be represented by matrices. See below for your problem:

```
library(nleqslv)


eqs_fun <- function(x) {
  y = numeric(2)
  y[1] = pnorm(q = (x[2]+1)/5) - pnorm(q = (x[1]+1)/5) - .025
  y[2] = pnorm(q = (x[2]-1)/5) - pnorm(q = (x[1]-1)/5) - .025
  y
}

xstart = c(0,1)
nleqslv(xstart, eqs_fun)
```

Running this should give you the following output:

```
list(x = c(-0.159856055122849, 0.159854416799285), fvec = c(1.006390991376e-09, 
-6.31374431903087e-10), termcd = 1L, message = "Function criterion near zero", 
    scalex = c(1, 1), nfcnt = 8L, njcnt = 1L, iter = 6L)
```

and you can yourself verify that c1 = -.16, c2 = .16 will give you a solution!

Comment: @rbeginner, click the check mark (tick mark) below the vote total on the answer's left.  That will accept the answer.